# What is alternative prev function in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Prev function is Jquery function. Is there an alternative to this in ReactJs? I did a lot of research. But I could not reach the result. 
I have tried before: previousElementSibling,previousSibling,nextElementSibling,nextSibling. They didn't solve my problem. Is there anybody who can help me about it?

```
 $("#diagram path[marker-end*='url']").prev('text');
```

Does this code have a counterpart in ReactJs?

Comment: There's no such function. You shouldn't think in jQuery. If you have specific problem, consider reasking the question with your case explained and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: 1. You shouldn't  need jquery with react. 2. There is no such thing. 3. Tell us what you want to achieve and we might be able to help you solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need jQuery if you work with React the way it's intended to:

> A big difference between these two is that React works through the “virtual DOM”, whereas jQuery interacts with the DOM directly. The virtual DOM is a DOM implementation in memory that compares to the existing DOM elements and makes the necessary changes/updates. And that leads to much faster performance.

[Source](https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/react-vs-jquery-how-they-compare/)

Go through the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) and give it a try. You won't regret it.